# React styling best practice . Global or Component Level

Tags: reactjs

I am working on react . Usually what i do is set all my styling in a seperate file aka global . I read that there are some other ways like component level styling or css in JS but unable to conclude which one should i use ??

Just want to know which way is suitable for what need ..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is the option to use something like [styled-componenents](https://www.styled-components.com/), [emotion](https://emotion.sh/docs/introduction) or other CSS-in-JS Frameworks. I think these are a good start. This looks something like this in styled-components.

```
const StyledDiv = styled.div`
  border: 1px solid red;
`

// react code
return <StyledDiv>Content</StyledDiv>
```

Its pretty straightforward, so I think its a good option to start there. 
My personal option is to use CSS-Modules (with Scss). Create-React-App does support it. And all you do is write normal CSS or SCSS and import it. Webpack will genereate scoped Classnames out of these CSS files. Looks something like this.

```
// styles.module.scss
.StyledDiv {
  border: 1px solid red;
}

// component.js
import styles from './styled.module.scss'

return <div className={styles.StyledDiv}> content </div>
```

This allows you to still use partials and mixins from Sass, while still having scoped your classNames like you would in styled-components. These would be my recommended options.

To answer your question. I would not recommend using globals styles, this could lead to multiple problems with styling and overwriting different styles. Component-scoped is better.

Comment: what are those problems ?

Comment: For instance overwriting styles, having an effect on elements which you dont want to, The need to care for specificity. Just to name some.
https://medium.com/seek-blog/the-end-of-global-css-90d2a4a06284
Just read something about css and global scope ;)